# Impute null values based on a group statistic

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I have a **copy dataset** using `df.dropna()` and I have compiled the mean of those data using `df.groupby` based on different groups with the converted code below assigned in:

```
# Suppose this is a result from df.groupby script

impute_data = pd.DataFrame({'PClass': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'Sex': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female',], 'Mean': [34, 29, 24, 40, 18, 25]})
```

Suppose I have this **real dataset** and I want to impute the missing values based on the means from **copy dataset**, how can it be achieved?

```
d = {'PClass': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1], 
     'Sex': ['male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'female'], 
     'Age': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My intial solution for this is an if else statement where for example if `Pclass=1 and Sex='male'` impute `34` and so on, but I am not certain on how I can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` after renaming `Mean` to `Age`:

```
impute_data.rename({'Mean':'Age'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df.update(impute_data)
```

Note that `update` occurs in place, you shouldn't assign it to another dataframe.